# guards in pattern match in let binding

Tags: haskell

I am surprised by the semantics of this (third expression below). Start here:

```
Prelude> let (a,b) = (0,0) in (a,b)
(0,0)
```

That's fine. Now add a guard, and it's still fine:

```
Prelude> let (a,b) | True = (0,0) in (a,b)
(0,0)
```

Now change the guard, and be surprised:

```
Prelude> let (a,b) | a == b = (0,0) in (a,b)
(^CInterrupted.
```

How come? - This works:

```
Prelude> case (0,0) of (a,b) | a == b -> (a,b)
(0,0)
```

Answer (score 8):

Guards in `let`-s mean "if the condition evaluates to True, bind lhs to rhs". Since Haskell `let`-s are recursive, `let (a,b) | a == b = (0,0) in (a,b)` first tries to evaluate `a == b` with `a` and `b` pointing back to the variables just being defined, which can be evaluated by checking again `a == b` in the guard, and this results in a loop. It's a loop for the same reason `let x = x in x` results in a loop when trying to force `x`.

Answer (score 6):

The let is equivalent to

```
let (a,b) = if a==b 
            then (0,0) 
            else error "non exhaustive..."
```

which shows its recursive nature more clearly.

Your misunderstanding comes from your let-to-case translation, which is not correct in the presence of guards (or recursion). To see why, think about how one would translate the following:

```
let (a,b) | condition1 = (0,0)
          | condition2 = (1,1)
```

The above can't be rewritten as something like `case (0,0) of (a,b) -> ...` or `case (1,1) of (a,b) -> ...`, since you need to evaluate the conditions before choosing between `(0,0)` and `(1,1)`.